# How many monitors can i connect to this gpu

Tags: multiple-monitors, gpu

I want to order this GPU: ASROCK Radeon RX 570 Phantom Gaming X 4G OC

I see that it has 3x DP 1.4, 1x HDMI 2.0, 1x Dual-link DVI-D

My question is can i connect 3x 1920x1080 75hz monitors to display ports + 1x HDMI 1920x1080 60hz?

and could it handle fifth monitor with Dual-link DVI-D 1920x1080x60hz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [product page for your card](https://www.asrock.com/Graphics-Card/AMD/Phantom%20Gaming%20X%20Radeon%20RX570%204G%20OC/#Specification) states

> Multi-view
>
> - 5

Which suggests that all 5 outputs can run simultaneously. I cannot say for certain though as I do not own one nor have 5 displays available.

If you do not have 3 DisplayPort capable monitors then you may need *active* (not passive) DisplayPort adaptors to connect to other devices. The outputs may function as HDMI outputs but may be otherwise limited with passive adaptors.

Comment: Yeah, i hope that they will all work :-D